# Vector calculus: is the element of surface area equal to 1?

Tags: integration, vector-analysis

We have $\textbf{r}(s,t)$ as the parametrization of a surface. Then the element of surface area is defined as $$dA = \left|\frac{\partial \textbf{r}}{\partial s}\times\frac{\partial \textbf{r}}{\partial t}\right|dsdt$$ where $|\cdot |$ represents the modulus.

Also, we know that the vector element of area $d \textbf{S} = \hat{\textbf{n}}dA$.

Hence we can write $$d \textbf{S} = \hat{\textbf{n}}dA=\hat{\textbf{n}}\left|\frac{\partial \textbf{r}}{\partial s}\times\frac{\partial \textbf{r}}{\partial t}\right|dsdt$$

but now recall that $\hat{\textbf{n}} = \left(\frac{\partial \textbf{r}}{\partial s}\times\frac{\partial \textbf{r}}{\partial t}\right)$ by definition! Therefore $|\hat{\textbf{n}} | = \left|\frac{\partial \textbf{r}}{\partial s}\times\frac{\partial \textbf{r}}{\partial t}\right|=1$ which tells us that $dA = dsdt$ and $d\textbf{S} = \hat{\textbf{n}} dsdt$.

> Then why don't we use these shorter notations? Furthermore, is there a flaw in my reasoning?

Comment: I suppose that $\mathbf{r}(s,t)$ is the parametrization of a surface, not a curve. Right?

Comment: Your normal vector isn't correct as it still needs to be divided by its own length. Also if you've ever worked in spherical polar coordinates it can immediately be seen that $dA \neq d\theta d\phi$

Comment: @EmilioNovati yes a surface, edited

Comment: @Triatticus true, found the stupid mistake. The expression would be $\textbf{n} = \left(\frac{\partial \textbf{r}}{\partial s}\times \frac{\partial \textbf{r}}{\partial t}\right)$ and the normed one is divided by the length. Hence we actually get the correct $d\textbf{S} =  \left(\frac{\partial \textbf{r}}{\partial s}\times \frac{\partial \textbf{r}}{\partial t}\right) dsdt$ since the two moduli cancel out

Comment: @Triatticus, if you wanna write an answer, for someone who in the future will make the same mistake as me, I'll accept it

Comment: Unfortunately I'm on mobile which makes for a terrible MathJaX editor so I will let someone else finalize the answer